# Adding oblique Birds Eye View from BING

Tags: qgis

I am trying to integrate the oblique birds eye view from the bing service in QGIS.
The documentation is referring to map tiles, however i don't get to load it in with the XYZ-Tiles service that is integrated in QGIS (i even got a bingkey).

Can anyone help?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-imagery-metadata

Comment: the birds eye orientation is not supported with xyz tiles, so incompatible.

Comment: go2streetview plugin if compatible for your version of qgis might be a solution https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/go2streetview/

Comment: thanks! yeah i tried that plugin but it looks like the support for the birds eye got discontinued in the new version.